# Using svg pattern without Id

Tags: svg

```
<svg width="192" height="192" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="image1" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="192" width="192">
            <image x="0" y="0" width="192" height="192" xlink:href="/url1"></image>
        </pattern>
        <pattern id="image2" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="192" width="192">
            <image x="0" y="0" width="192" height="192" xlink:href="/url2"></image>
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="m0,0 l0,192 l192,-192 z" fill="url(#image1)" />
    <path d="M192,0 l-192,192 l192,0 z" fill="url(#image2)" />
</svg>
```

In the example above I used id `#image1` and `#image2` to let paths refer to the patterns. This is ok for one time usage but if I'm going to repeat this html somewhere else in the document, all the paths will refers to the last patterns with the given id.
How can I use SVG pattern/ image to fill a path without assigning an ID to the pattern ?

Edit: Would love to have some help to get above svg block more efficient. I'm new to SVG.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using IDs, but if so, I will need to make sure all patterns have different IDs so the images will be different. Would be great if could have something like nested pattern definition inside path

Comment: There's no way to avoid ids.

Comment: How sad. if the job of ID is to help get reference to the pattern, why wouldn't it support setting the reference directly to Node

Comment: What's so hard about a unique id?

Comment: Just personal preference. I normally prefer to point to element directly. (Also help me avoid overhead of querying the element from parentNode / document)

Comment: You could always [contact w3c](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-svg/) and put your idea to them. It might then appear in a new version of the SVG specification.

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you are going to repeat this exact SVG elsewhere in the document, then you can always just define it once in your document and reference it from everywhere you need it by making use of `<use>`.